# How a function with parameter `findRow(s)` is called on a specific script?

Tags: javascript, function, google-apps-script

This code works perfectly well. I just don't understand why.
Can someone explain how function `findRow(s)` is "called"?
I don't see what makes function `findRow(s)` run.

I see how they've defined the `var rA=findRow(resp.getResponseText());`

It doesn't seem to make sense to me that this makes the function run. 
I'm obviously very green at this... does the act of just defining the variable make that next function "work"?
Or is it the `Logger.log` part that starts the work?

```
function findAString(){
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh1=ss.getActiveSheet();
  var sh2=ss.getSheetByName('Completed');
  var resp=SpreadsheetApp.getUi().prompt("Enter a String");
  var s=resp.getResponseText();
  if(s){
    var rA=findRow(s);
    if (rA.length>0){
      sh2.getRange(sh2.getLastRow()+1,1,rA.length,rA[0].length).setValues(rA);
      var rows='<br /><h3>Order details have been moved to the Completed     tab</h3><br />';
      rows+=Utilities.formatString(resp.getResponseText());
      for(var i=0;i<rA.length;i++){
        rows+=Utilities.formatString('<br /> %s',rA[i].join('<br />'));
      }
      rows+='<br /><br /><input type="button" value="Exit" onClick="google.script.host.close();" />';
  if(rows){
    var ui=HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(rows);
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(ui, 'Search Results')
  }
}
  }else{
    throw('Error: Invalid Response');
  }
}

function findRow(s) { ;// the actual search function
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var sh = ss.getActiveSheet()
    var rA=[];
    var vA=sh.getDataRange().getValues();
    for(var i=0;i<vA.length;i++) {
      for(var j=0;j<vA[i].length;j++){
        if(vA[i][j].toString().indexOf(s)>-1){
          rA.push(vA[i]);
          break;
        }
      }
    }
    return rA;
  var sourcesheet = ss.getSheetByName('Form Responses 2');
  var targetsheet = ss.getSheetByName('Completed');
  var targetrange = targetsheet.getRange(targetsheet.getLastRow(), 1, sourcesheet.getLastRow(), sourcesheet.getLastColumn());
  var rangeValues = sourcesheet.getRange(2, 1, sourcesheet.getLastRow(), sourcesheet.getLastColumn()).getValues();
   targetrange.setValues(rangeValues);
}
```

Comment: You will be well served by completing javascript tutorials. Review the difference between an argument and a function parameter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you already mentioned findRow function is called by

```
var rA=findRow(resp.getResponseText());
```

Considering that a few code lines it is var `s=resp.getResponseText();`, you could rewrite it to save some characters like this:

```
 var rA=findRow(s);
```

Above the above line is

```
 var resp=SpreadsheetApp.getUi().prompt("Enter a String");
```

This line assigns a PromptResponse object to `resp`. The PromptResponse object has the method `getResponseText()` which returns a String object.

The `Logger.log(rA)` just logs the String value to the log.

References

- [Functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Functions)